# How do I access the data of a field using PHP?

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm trying to print out different links to an e-mail based on the values selected in the in the multi-select field. I've used devel to make sure that the field is actually storing the values and it is, but it always goes to the default case in my switch. I am trying to access the information from a node.

```
    print("I am in the php tag");
    $field_lab = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_lab_s_requested');
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
       print("I am in the for loop" + "Count:" + ($i+1));
        $lab = $field_lab['und']['value'][$i];
        switch ($lab) {
            case "127":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "129":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "130":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "132":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "117":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "112":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "113":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "116":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "118":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "121":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "122":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "119":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "123":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "124":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "140":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "143":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "146":
                print("link");
                break;
            case "148":
                print("link");
                break;

            default:
                print("Hit the default case");
                break;
}
```

}

Comment: A word of advice: Install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and you can do `dpm($variable, 'custom label');` instead of doing `print('custom label: ' . $variable);`. This way arrays are very nicely readable and it helps you learn the structures and inspect values at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language negotiation is handled for you by `field_get_items`, and the delta is above the field column in the array hierarchy (it goes `$field[LANGUAGE][DELTA][COLUMN_NAME]`).

So using `und` isn't necessary, and you need to change how you're accessing each field item.

Code similar to this should work:

```
$field_lab = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_lab_s_requested');
foreach ($field_lab as $field_item) {
  switch ($field_item['value']) {
    case "127":

      break;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I will get it a shot and let you know what happens. Thanks for such a quick answer!

Comment: Still kicking to the default case.

Comment: That would only happen if the value was the same in each loop iteration. Print out `$field_item['value'];` in each iteration; if the value is the same, your problem is with the data, not the code

Comment: Looks like it's with the data, nothing is printing out.